# Best alternative to constants interface/class in this particular case?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and I'm making a game, at the current moment, I'm coding some of the character classes, I'll have something like

`(Abstract)Character
  ^            ^
  |            |
PlayableChar.  EnemyChar.`

Where the arrows symbolize inheritance (probably more classes/subclasses in between).

Coming from a C, it felt natural to define an interface/non-instantiable class filled with constants (`MAX_HP_PLAYER, MAX_ATTACK,...`), as I'll need to use these constants in a lot of places, probably not just in the classes under the Character hierarchy. However, I've read here and in many places that this is not seen as really good practice, and I haven't found what's the recommended solution in this sort of scenarios.

Could somebody help me out? Thanks!

Comment: You can have them be `public` under the class they're associated with. Other classes will still be able to access them, but they'll be in a logical place.

Comment: Something like ```MAX_HP_PLAYER``` should be part of the ```Player``` class as ```MAX_HP``` don't you think? Why use a separate class?

Comment: From an oo point of view, you'd want to try and define the constants within the context that they should be used, so you might have a Charater interface which also defines the constants associated with the character in particular, but as you flesh out the hierarchy, you may add new constants to child interfaces as they need them, as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd define them as `final` (and maybe `static`, depending on whether all your characters have the same e.g. `MAX_HP` - in which case `static` makes sense) inside your `Character` class as that's the best context for them (from what I can gather, the constants refer to a character's e.g. `MAX_HP` etc.).